# i have a image sharing script. the max allowed file upload is 5MB what should i set my max_input_time and my max_execution_time?

Tags: php, apache, upload, timeout, execution

I ask because since max_input_time is the only that should be set accordingly to facilitate the upload process, how would you ever know what to set it to. Everyone's connection is different some may take longer to upload then others.

Also what are the risks of setting it too high? For example if i choose to allow users to upload bigger files then 5MB.

Please give me as much details as possible on the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use  this for big size file upload in .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

php_value post_max_size 200M

php_value max_execution_time 80000

php_value max_input_time 80000
```

Comment: what are the risks of using 80000 it seems liek a very big number? if there are no risks.. why not use unlimited?

Comment: Exectime does not count upload time. Have never user inputtime but uploaded movies (500mb) without problems. Just remember the formfield as well.